# CListCtrl with checkboxes questions

Tags: checkbox, mfc, side-effects, clistctrl

The List Control is defined as Single Selection on the resources.

**Question 1**

I want to have a checkbox on the header of first column of my `CListCtrl`. On the `OnInitDialog` I have

```
    m_list.SetExtendedStyle(m_list.GetExtendedStyle() | LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES | LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT);

    CString s;
    s.LoadString(IDS_COLUMN1);

    #ifndef HDS_CHECKBOXES
    // Copied from Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include\CommCtrl.h
    #define HDS_CHECKBOXES  0x0400
    #endif 

    CHeaderCtrl& header = *m_list.GetHeaderCtrl();
    header.ModifyStyle(0, HDS_CHECKBOXES);


    #ifndef HDF_CHECKBOX
    // Copied from Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include\CommCtrl.h    
    #define HDF_CHECKBOX  0x0040
    #endif 

    LVCOLUMN lc = { 0 };
    lc.mask = LVCF_FMT |LVCF_WIDTH |LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_SUBITEM;
    lc.fmt |= HDF_CHECKBOX;
    lc.cx = 96;
    lc.pszText = (TCHAR*) (LPCTSTR)s;

    m_list.InsertColumn(0, &lc);
```

It only presents the header's checkbox if I add in the extended `|LVS_EX_AUTOCHECKSELECT`, which I definitely not want because I desire that checking action and selection action will be used for different purposes.

**Question 2**

I need to set a boolean and mark thing as modified when user checks or unchecks an item. But I don't want this action to occur when inserting items, for example when filling the list at form loading, but it is triggered without my intention, as `InsertItem` triggers "a uncheck action" on `OnItemChanged`.

It obliged me to condition every insert with a `m_is_inserting` member flag:

```
    m_is_inserting = true;
    m_list.InsertItem(i, m_array[i]->GetName());
    m_is_inserting = false;
```

and react accordingly on the `LVN_ITEMCHANGED` handler

```
void CMyDialog::OnItemChanged(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    NMLISTVIEW* pNMListView = (NM_LISTVIEW*)pNMHDR;

    if (pNMListView->uChanged & LVIF_STATE)
    {
        if (pNMListView->uNewState & LVIS_SELECTED)
            OnSelect();
        else
        {
            if (pNMListView->iItem != -1)
            {
                if ((pNMListView->uNewState & LVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK) == 0x1000)
                {
                    if (!m_is_inserting)
                    {
                        m_array[pNMListView->iItem]->m_active = false;
                        SetModified();
                    }
                }
                else if ((pNMListView->uNewState & LVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK) == 0x2000)
                {
                    if (!m_is_inserting)
                    {
                        m_array[pNMListView->iItem]->m_active = true;
                        SetModified();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    *pResult = 0;
}
```

Is there a better way to distinguish a real user check/uncheck action from a `InsertItem` side effect?

**Question 3**

Is there a better symbolic convention for getting the check/uncheck state? Magic numbers `0x1000` and `0x2000` are pretty meaningless!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related (**Question 2**): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28582698/differentiate-between-user-click-and-setchecked-in-clistctrl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert the column headers first. Then change the `HDF_CHECKBOX`. For example:

```
m_list.SetExtendedStyle(LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES| LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT);

CHeaderCtrl &header = *m_list.GetHeaderCtrl();
header.ModifyStyle(0, HDS_CHECKBOXES);

m_list.InsertColumn(0, L"Column0", 0, 120, 0);
m_list.InsertColumn(1, L"Column1", 0, 80, 1);
m_list.InsertColumn(2, L"Column2", 0, 80, 2);

HDITEM hdi = { 0 };
hdi.mask = HDI_FORMAT;
header.GetItem(0, &hdi);
hdi.fmt |= HDF_CHECKBOX;
header.SetItem(0, &hdi);

m_list.InsertItem(m_list.GetItemCount(), L"C0", 0);
m_list.InsertItem(m_list.GetItemCount(), L"C1", 0);

m_list.SetCheck(0, 1);
m_list.SetCheck(1, 1);
```

When handling the notification you can use the `GetCheck` method to see if item is checked or not. Example:

```
if(pNMListView->uChanged & LVIF_STATE)
{
    if(pNMListView->uNewState & LVIS_SELECTED)
    {
        ...
    }
    else if(pNMListView->uNewState & LVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK && pNMListView->iItem >= 0)
    {
        if(m_list.GetCheck(pNMListView->iItem))
            TRACE("%d checked\n", pNMListView->iItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. You got the "How to present a checkbox on the header" part (**Question 1**) of my question answered. Didn't try the handling the notification yet. Side note:  it is very likely the feature of having a checkbox on header for `CMFCListCtrl`/`CMFCHeaderCtrlist` not even implemented, as I don't find occurences of `HDS_CHECKBOXES`, `HDF_CHECKBOX` and `HDF_CHECKED` on the `afxheaderctrl.cpp|h`and `afxlistctrl.cpp|h` files!

Comment: What's purpose of `header.SetItem(0, &hdi);`? The first column could be checkbox list even without this part of code.

Comment: @Zhang Yes, `header.SetItem(0, &hdi)` is not necessary. It puts a checkbox in the header control, optional.