# virtual ClistCtrl with checkboxes on displayed report list style

Tags: clistctrl

I have an MFC SDI application to display a list of data read from a csv file. So I set up its view to be inherited from CListView and make it a virtual list control. That means I have to use LVS_OWNERDATA as one of its CListCtrl style attributes. Yet I now run into a problem when I have to include Checkboxes in  each row of the displayed list. As you might know, LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES can't be used with LVS_OWNERDATA, I therefore create a bitmap file to contain 2 small images of checkbox (selected and de-selected) and toggle them every time the user clicks on the loaded image/icon. I am handling this in OnNMClick method. And I have two problems I would like to ask for your help to solve.

(1) I don't know how to update the virtual list (which is commonly handled in OnLvnGetdispinfo method) so I try this in OnNMClick and find that the check and unchecked images aren't toggled.

```
void CMFCSDITest::OnNMClick(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    LPNMITEMACTIVATE pNMItemActivate = reinterpret_cast<LPNMITEMACTIVATE>(pNMHDR);
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    *pResult = 0; 
    LVHITTESTINFO hitinfo;
    hitinfo.pt = pNMItemActivate->ptAction;

    int nItem = pListCtrl->HitTest(&hitinfo);

    if (hitinfo.flags != LVHT_ONITEMICON)
        return; 
    NMLVDISPINFO *pDispInfo = reinterpret_cast<NMLVDISPINFO*>(pNMHDR);
    LV_ITEM* pItem = &(pDispInfo)->item;
    if (pItem->iImage == 0)
        pItem->iImage = 1;
    else
        pItem->iImage = 0;
    pListCtrl->SetItem(pItem);
    pListCtrl->UpdateWindow(); //this is wrong as nothing seems updated after all.
}
```

Given that the created imagelist is inserted into the pListCtrl already (in OnInitialUpdate method) and I set the output image index value in OnLvnGetdispinfo method.

(2) Instead of handling OnNMClick, I read somewhere people's advice that OnLvnItemchanged method could also be used. However in `LPNMLISTVIEW` struct, there is `uNewState` and `uOldState` variable members for which I don't know how to set up my tiny checked and unchecked icons as status images. Because I might have to do this

```
if (pNMLV->uChanged & LVIF_STATE)
{
    switch (pNMLV->uNewState & LVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK)
    {
       case image1://do
       case image2://do
    }
}
```

Comment: See **Question 2** and **Question 3** of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41176599/clistctrl-with-checkboxes-questions for *How to use `uNewState` and `uOldState`*.

Comment: It is possible. I created a custom CListCtrl derived class and implemented the State Image list. I think [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7891/Using-virtual-lists) describes the basics for the implementation. Basically you need to change the state in ItemChanging and itemChanged events and and also override GetCheck/SetCheck to change the state with the `INDEXTOSTATEIMAGEMASK` macro